# React router: userHistory push function is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, browser-history

I'm trying to change the browser URL and render the desired component based on some condition. however, I'm able to change the URL after successful login and land the user to /home page but when I'm trying to change the URL on button click, it hits the /accounts URL and changes to /home again.

**App.js**

```
  <Route exact path="/accounts" component={Accounts} />
  <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
  <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
</Switch>
```

after successful login from component A, I'm executing below piece of code which renders home components

```
 setInterval(() => {
            history.push("/home")
          }, 300);
```

once the user performs a button click in /home i'm executing below piece of code to change the url and render accounts component.

```
 function showAccountsTransactions () {
        history.replace("/accounts")
    }

  return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
<Fab onClick={showAccountsTransactions}>
                 Show Account and Transactions
        </Fab>
 </div>
```

but i could see that onClick, the url is getting changed to /accounts and switches back to /home. Could you guys please suggest some idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have got yourself a scheduler.

```
 setInterval(() => {
            history.push("/home")
          }, 300);
```

The code above resets the URL to `/home` at every 300ms(0.3s), no matter where you go.

`setTimeOut` and `setIntervals` are never made to be used for routing. so Don't.

A few more best practices would be to avoid using `history.replace()` and use `history.push()` instead. Its not a right idea to change history stack of routes.

Also when you use `<Switch>`, there is no need to use `exact` everywhere. They are just alternatives for each other, at different circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant piece of explanation. I dint notice that silly mistake. I have made the all the changes suggested by you and it works perfectly